# Understanding upgrade script for clamAv + Setting up sync between 2 servers via SFTP

Tags: clamav

I have setup `ClamAV` in my client systems. Unfortunately, all our ports are protected and blocked and we have access to only 2 ports in total.

- Port 1: From this port, we will able to execute Linux commands remotely from server
- Port 2: SFTP port for file transfer.

We are sure we will not be given access for extra ports. So now I am trying to find a way for setting up anti-virus.

Implementation expectation:

1. Setup a small apache server
2. Setup a Private Local Mirrors
3. Download signature / definitions from clamAv mirror
4. Get current version from clientX
5. Prepare update patch to client
6. SFTP the patch database to client machine (location will be ROOT path of localhost server)
7. client will be configured for getting updates from localhost server

To achieve this I was just trying to understand how `clamdownloader.pl` works.

On that front I notice that after getting `CDIFF` it is downloading `daily.cvd`, which is about 54MB, which I feel is very high.
Since bandwidth is very limited in my network need some advice on way forward.

Comment: I believe you perform  a DNS query to see if new definitions are available. 54MB isn't unreasonable, I'm afraid. There are a lot of virus definitions required these days.

Comment: @roaima : Yeah 54MB is ok for my main server for client i think its too large.. I am worried my SFTP does not handle that much bandwidth.